# How to set dynamic height of imageview in table cell based on downloaded image from url

Tags: swift

I am using Kingfisher library to download image

```
cell.doseImg.kf.setImage(with: URL(string: imgUrl))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this line in heightForRowAt index table delegate after image download

```
if let image = doseImg.image {
   let ratio = image.size.width / image.size.height
      newHeight = (self.view.frame.width / ratio) + 107
}
      return newHeight
```

Answer (score 0):

1.Set top,bottom and trilling constraints for the image.

2.add below code in viewDidLoad().

```
tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 140
```

Comment: it's not working , when i load page for first time it set row height by estimatedRowHeight and when i add more data at last index of table than previous cells height set by automatic and new cells set as same as estimatedRowHeight